# parameter packs parameter type

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, parameter-pack

I have modified the sample from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack to save the string in a variable. My code

```
#include <string>

void tprintf(std::string& str, const std::string& format) 
{
    str += format; 
}

template <typename T, typename... Targs>
void tprintf(std::string& str, const std::string& format, T arg, Targs ...Fargs)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < format.size(); i++ )
    {
        if ( format.at(i) == '%' )
        {
            if (format.at(i + 1) == 'd') 
            {
                std::cout << "== 'd' -variable = " << arg << std::endl;
                str += std::to_string(arg);
            }
            else if (format.at(i + 1) == 's') 
            {
                std::cout << "== 's'" << std::endl;
                str += arg;
            }
            tprintf(str, (i + 2 < format.size() ? format.substr(i + 2) : ""), Fargs...);
            break;  
        }
        str += format.at(i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    int age = 24;
    std::string name("Hugo");
    tprintf(str, "Name: %s, age: %d years\n", name, age);
    std::cout << "result = " << str << std::endl;
}
```

When compile the code I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘to_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’
                 str += std::to_string(arg);
```

I thought the parameter pack expands to

1. `tprintf(std::string&, const std::string&, std::string, int)` <- `arg` is `std::string`
2. `tprintf(std::string&, const std::string&, int)` <- `arg` is `int` and I can call `std::to_string(arg)`
   But it seems that `arg` has another type than `int` (`std::string` or something else)?
   When I remove the `std::to_string` call I get some cryptic characters.

How can I convert the value for the age to a `string` and append it to `str`?

Comment: `name` is an `std::string` passed to `arg`, but there is no overload for an `std::string` argument in `to_string` since it's already a string. Ngl though, I certainly sometimes wish there was an overload for `std::string` which just did nothing and returned a string for these kind of situations.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 `to_string` has other shortcomings, the thing is that it is meant to convert the same as `std::sprintf`, and there is also no `sprintf` to convert from `std::string`s

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 I call to_string for the int variable (age) after the first recursive call of tprintf. If I understand correctly, the function call looks like this tprintf(std::string& str, const std::string& format, int arg).

Comment: That doesn't mean that the code that calls `to_string` isn't compiled both times. It still has to compile the `to_string(arg)` even when the format specifier is not `%d` which results in the error when it's a string.

Comment: Off-topic: `at` implements an additional range check, which is entirely obsolete within for loops like yours that are based on the vector's range. You should prefer `operator[]` in such cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> tprintf(std::string&, const std::string&, std::string, int) <- arg is
> std::string

Correct, therefore, here:

```
 str += std::to_string(arg);
```

`arg` is a `std::string`, and there is no such `std::to_string` overload.

No matter what type `T` is, the resulting template must be valid C++ code. Even if the corresponding formatting character is `d`, everything in the function must still be valid C++ code.

In general, attempting to implement C-style `printf` formatting, in type-safe C++ doesn't make much sense. You already know what needs to be formatted simply by the virtue of the fact that you know the type of the corresponding parameter.

The only reason you have different formatting specifiers in C-style `printf` strings, such as `%s` or `%d`, is because this C function has no clue, whatsoever, what is getting to passed to it, as a parameter, so it relies on the actual formatting specifier to know what it is.

This obviously isn't the case with C++. Your formatting specifier can be just a `%`, by itself, with nothing else. You know exactly what parameter gets passed in. Therefore, it's much simpler to merely define three overloaded functions:

```
template <typename... Targs>
void tprintf(std::string& str, const std::string& format, int arg, Targs ...args)
{
   // Just the code that formats an int
}

template <typename... Targs>
void tprintf(std::string& str, const std::string& format, const std::string &arg, Targs ...args)
{
   // Just the code that formats a std::string
}

void tprintf(std::string& str, const std::string& format)
{
   // Nothing more to format, just adds everything else in "format" to "str".
}
```

In the first two cases, all that needs to happen is to search `format` for the first `%` place-holder by itself, copy everything before prior to it into `str`, followed by the formatted parameter, and then recursively re-invoke `tprintf`  with the remaining `args`, and what's left in the `format`.

P.S. Using forwarding references, "Targs && ...args", together with `std::forward`, will be a follow-up tweak.

Answer (score 1):

All branches of an if statement are compiled.  The compiler is attempting to pass the string argument to to string, and no overload exists.

The fact that it doesn't happen at runtime is irrelevant.  At compile time, the compiler needs to know what

```
tprintf(str, "Name: %s, age: %d years\n", name, age);
```

does **and** what

```
tprintf(str, "Name: %d, age: %d years\n", name, age);
```

would do.

Consider not including type information twice.  You already know that name is a string and age is an integer, repeating it in the format string is pointless.

I'd advise positional commands in a format string, as that makes localization far more practical as well.